# browser freezes after using <Redirect to="" /> component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

i am using `"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",`

i want to protect the main page from unauthorized access, so in the main page i have this:

```
  render() {
      return (
        <AuthProvider>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/info/infoSignup" component={InfoSignup} />
              <Route path="/info/infoLogin" component={InfoLogin} />
              <Route path="/info/forgotPassword" component={ForgotPassword} />
              <Route
                path="/info/addUserData"
                render={(props) => (
                  <AddUserData {...props} />
                )}
              />
              <Route
                path="/info/editUserData"
                render={(props) => (
                  <EditUserData
                    {...props}
                    updateUserDataHandler={this.updateUserDataHandler}
                  />
                )}
              />
              <InfoPrivacy 
              path="/"
              component={(props) => (
                <ViewUsersDataTable  {...props}
                usersData={this.state.usersData}
                removeUserDataById={this.removeUserDataHandler}
                renderUsersData = {this.renderUsersData}
                 />
              )}


              />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
          
        </div>
        </AuthProvider>
      
      );    
  }
```

and the `<InfoPrivacy />` component is like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuth } from './contexts/AuthContext';

export default function InfoPrivacy({component: Component, ...rest}) {
    const { currentUser } = useAuth();

    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={props => {
                // return currentUser ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/info/infoLogin" />
                return currentUser ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/info/infoLogin" />
            }}
        >
            
        </Route>
    );
}
```

in the main page, i have a **logout** button which triggers this function:

```
export function logout() {
    return auth.signOut();
}
```

i successfully get logged out and redirected to the login page, which i exactly what i want, but the problem is after the redirection, the browser freezes for couple of seconds then i get this error:

```
TypeError: location is undefined
createPath
node_modules/history/esm/history.js:47

  44 |   };
  45 | }
  46 | function createPath(location) {
> 47 |   var pathname = location.pathname,
  48 |       search = location.search,
  49 |       hash = location.hash;
  50 |   var path = pathname || '/';
```

Comment: how do you define `location` used inside of `createPath(location)` ? share that code.

Comment: i didn't define that value, its the code inside the history package, in node_modules/history/esm/history.js:47

Comment: I see, I think you'll need to debug the code, set break points and trace why this is happening, only then you'll know what to fix. Start from the logout function, see how you handle the logout and what you do next after it's logged out.